# Do the balloon colours mean anything?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Sometimes balloons with presents float by that you can shoot down with your slingshot. They come in various colours - I have seen red ones and yellow ones and blue ones.

Sometimes you get money or items or DIY recipes - do the colours of the balloon tell you anything about what you will get from the present, or is it just random?

Comment: Well, there are also egg balloons but we don't talk about those

Comment: Hush your mouth, those are just a bad dream, I am sure of it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any definitive, data-mined data but I've shot over 300 balloons so far. I can confirm the anectdotal information from [several](https://www.polygon.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-switch-acnh-guide/2020/4/3/21205849/balloon-colors-gifts-slingshot-recipes-how-to-get) [guides](http://www.nintendolife.com/guides/animal-crossing-new-horizons-balloons-balloon-spawn-rate-hunting-and-colour-guide) [on](https://gamerant.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-balloon-colors-blue-green-red-yellow-recipes-bells/) animal crossing balloon colours:

Any balloon can contain anything. I've gotten furniture and clothes from all colours of balloons.

But yellow balloons are the only ones I've seen to contain bells, and blue ones often carry crafting materials like clay, iron or gold. I can't remember shooting any blue, red or green balloons that contained bells.

There's still some difference between guides on what red/green balloons contain most, I did notice all of my recent seasonal DIY recipes came from red balloons. But since they also often drop furniture for me, it may well be those are the ones you mostly get furniture from.

I know of only two balloons where the color would tell you something about the present: The bunny day balloons that dropped sky eggs, and the golden balloon that gives you your golden slingshot DIY recipe.